# mysql design for dynamic html field form

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic

I have a dynamic form field in my HTML form .

In this form user fills websites and hobbies.
Here `website` and `hobby` are `dynamic fields` i.e there can be many input field of websites and hobby as user want.

To store these fields my database design is this:

```
Users      Website-Link       Website                
pk: ID      PK: User-ID       PK: ID
            PK: WEbsite-Id    WEbsite-url(varchar)
```

Hobby field has same deign as of Website with Hobby and Hobby-Link table.

I am making following queries to store data in mysql database

```
Foreach website url:
     Insert WEbsite url in Website Table . this gives me website ID
     Insert User Id and Website ID in Website-Link Table
End Lop
```

Similarly for Hobby Fields.

My question is that Is there any other smart way to do above things?

Is my design right?

Comment: It's a many to many relationship. You can't reinvent the wheel. If hobbies and websites aren't linked, you're doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not need Website-Link table:

```
Users      Website                
pk: ID     PK: ID
           User-ID
           WEbsite-url(varchar)
```

The loop become:

```
Foreach website url:
   Insert WEbsite url in Website Table 
   Insert User Id in Website Table 
End Lop
```